# Duvida Distinct com Doctrine_Query

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Tenho uma tabela em mysql e preciso retornar valores únicos desta tabela só que não estou conseguindo criar uma function ou uma consulta que se adapte. A instrução SQL no banco seria assim e funciona certinho, só que em Doctrine não consigo fazer :

```
SELECT DISTINCT anodecorrente FROM ct_noticias WHERE categoria = 'Infanto' ORDER BY nt_id ASC
```

Tenho a classe que mapeia a tabela em `Doctrine` como `CtNoticias`.

Comment: Ajuda aí pessoal !!!, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 0):

Tete a seguinte DQL:

```
$this
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT DISTINCT(c.anodecorrente)
        FROM CtNoticias c
        WHERE c.categoria = :categoria')
        ORDER BY c.ntId ASC
    ->setParameter('categoria', $categoria)
    ->getResult();
```

Você pode ter que atualizar os nomes das propriedades para os nomes dos modelos da sua classe `CtNoticias`.